# Best place for media query in css

Tags: css, media-queries

I want to write media query for my css codes , but i wonder how i can write best code for better performance

My present code ( its just an example , I do that when i have many code )

```
.element1 {font-size : 20px}
@media only and screen ( max-width:700px)
{
      .element1 {font-size : 30px}
}

.element2 {font-size : 30px}
@media only and screen ( max-width:700px)
{
      .element2 {font-size : 40px}
}
```

But i have also seen like this

```
.element1 {font-size : 20px}
.element2 {font-size : 30px}
    @media only and screen ( max-width:700px)
    {
          .element1 {font-size : 30px}
          .element2 {font-size : 40px}
    }
```

Is there any difference between these codes ? 
Which of them is better ?

Comment: It is good to define media queries at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

either use media queries at the end of the stylesheet or make separate css file for media queries.

Comment: OK while coding, but when the project is done better have it all in one place. One request less and Google speed test is happy.

Comment: So put all in the end of the CSS file ?

Answer (score 1):

It basically comes down to preference. The performance impact is minimal,  here's a link to some stats logged: http://aaronjensen.github.io/media_query_test/

It comes down to: grouping by component or grouping by query.

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by queries is, IMHO, the most legible way to implement media queries. Especially if you are in "normal" css (I mean : you don't work with a preprocessor as Sass or Less).

If you group by components, it's simple : **what if you need to change the value of a breakpoint ?** You'll need to change all the value in all the queries you set.

And by the way, making a query by component makes much more code.

Put all the queries in the end of a CSS file (or in a separate file if you can concatenate it in production).